# I need help with my first seedlings

Tags: seedlings, basil, cilantro

The cilantro have grown a lot of true leaves but not so much the basil and oregano. I planted them all at the same time. I don’t know if im supposed to thin any of them out now and how exactly to thin them out.[image][image][image]

Also i planted them exactly 3 weeks ago on march 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When seedlings get true leaves they can be transplanted to larger containers. Your Cilantro is ready for transplanting. The other two (Basil and Oregano) still have to form true leaves (or in case of Oregano: can grow larger overall), you can wait until they have true leaves larger then the cotyledons.

Furthermore, your Cilantro and Basil looks leggy. This is caused by not sufficient light, best is to give them a few hours direct sunlight per day.

Comment: ... but don’t expose them to full sun without hardening them off or they’d get sunburned. Otherwise good post!

Comment: Thanks @Stephie, a few hours is hardening right?

Comment: I would start with dappled shade instead of full sun, speaking from experience >.< I have scorched seedlings before, sadly. And transplanted seedlings are especially vulnerable as long as their roots haven’t re-anchored and can’t supply the plant.

Comment: Yes they are vulnerable directly after transplanting, thank you for that addition! Another tip for transplanting the leggy Cilantro, put them a little bit deeper in the new pots.